# VBA- How to change value in cell range if met condition

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to ask how to change value in cell range.

I want to change value in cell range in column C to column Q if met condition in Column B 
If cell in Column B = FALSE then all values in column C to Q will change to "0"

[image]

the result will be like this..

[image]

I have tried with code but it takes so long time to run because I use so many "IF"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it instantly from VBA...

```
Sub Brexlin()

    [c1:q5] = [if(c1:a5,c1:q5,)]

End Sub
```

---

Update

After your comments, please see the updated answer below...

```
Sub Brexlin()

    [c1:q5] = [if(b1:b5="DARK",c1:q5,)]

End Sub
```

Comment: Did you try this?

Comment: If your range is really small you won't notice any difference between Brexlin() and ZeroMaker(). However, Brexlin() is orders of magnitude quicker to execute on large ranges.

Comment: Could you please explain how this code work? I tried but then it's all changed to 0 even column B.

Comment: Are your ranges exactly the same as your picture?

Comment: I mean is your range B1:Q5? It works perfectly. But you must change it properly if you are using a different range. Notice that there are THREE ranges in the code and all three will need to be changed.

Comment: Once all of those calculations are concluded, the resulting array of values is returned to VBA. 
And then that array of values is assigned to the output range (on the left side of the equal sign.
This is an extremely fast operation. However, you  must setup the THREE ranges properly for your actual situation. I am happy to get it going for you, if you send me your workbook.

Comment: I have tried with your code and I changed a bit. It quite works perfectly but the fact is I probably messed up with the question because the value in column B are not exactly TRUE or FALSE but 2 keywords (2 type of items) like when cell in column B is "WHITE" then all value in column C-Q = 0, if "DARK" then all value in column C-Q remain the same. I'm really glad for your help. :)

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect your the information you provided in your last comment. This will work to keep the data in rows that start with "DARK" and make the rows that start with anything else (WHITE, for example) to change to zeros. Please select this answer because it is faster and more concise. And the larger the data range it operates on, the bigger it's speed advantage becomes.

Comment: I have change a bit to match my condition and it now works perfectly. very fast version. Thank you so much Excel Hero! and all of you guys. appreciate a lot. :)

Comment: If i could up-vote this answer more than once, I would!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks. I wish you could!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure where/how you are getting your values, but by placing

```
=IF($B1 = FALSE, 0, "YourValueSource")
```

in C1 and copying thru to Qn (where n is last row number) will handle setting values to 0.  Now you just need to add code to replace "YourValueSource" with the value or formula you want in each cell.

Answer (score 1):

Give this simple macro a try:

```
Sub ZeroMaker()
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = False Then Range(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i, "Q")).Value = 0
    Next i
End Sub
```